# Saving data with ajax to wordpress custom database issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress

As this is my first wp plugin in wanted to use AJAX to let users save there data(thru an form) to the plugin custom db(yes it must be my own table).

The issue:

If I submit the form it will redirect the page to the ajax processing file(save-to-db-ajax.php) which it obvious shouldn't do. Below the three parts of the plugin.

```
  // admin/includes/form.php

  <form method="post" id="form-settings" action="<?php echo PLUGIN_ADMIN_AJAX_PATH;?>/save-to-db-ajax.php" >  

      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'settings', 'settings_nonce', false );?> 

      <input    name="field-one" type="text"/>
      <input    name="field-two" type="text"/>
      <textarea name="field_three">Hello world</textarea>

      <button name="save-form">Save</button>

  </form>




  // admin/js/admin.js(part of the admin.js file, the rest works)

  $('body').on('submit', '#form-settings', function(e){

      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: $('#form-settings').attr('action'),
          data: $('#form-settings').serialize(),
          beforeSend: function() {
              alert('before')
          },
          success: function(){
              alert('success')
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('error')
          },
      }); 
  });



  // admin/ajax/save-to-db-ajax.php

  global $wpdb;

  $wpdb->update( 'my_plugin_table' ,
      array( 'settings_value' => $_POST[ 'field-one' ] ),
      array( 'settings_name'  => 'field-one'           ),
      array( '%s' , '%s' )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress ajax is done a little differently! You add a action to the ajax handler and use an central ajax handler as the url. In most themes its the js var ajaxurl. If its not defined google it.

Note: i didnt check your DB function

html:

```
    <form method="post" id="form-settings" action="" >  

      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'settings', 'settings_nonce', false );?> 

      <input    name="field-one" type="text"/>
      <input    name="field-two" type="text"/>
      <textarea name="field_three">Hello world</textarea>

      <button id="submitme" name="save-form">Save</button>

  </form>
```

jQuery: (if placed in footer, if elsewhere wrap in jQuery(document).ready(function(){});

```
  jQuery(document).on('click', '#submitme', function(event){ // use jQuery no conflict methods replace $ with "jQuery"

        event.preventDefault(); // stop post action

      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: ajaxurl, // or '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'
          data: {
              'action': 'ajax_form',
              'field-one': jQuery('[field-one]').val()// or combine serialized form with action .... 
          },
          beforeSend: function() {
              alert('before')
          },
          success: function(){
              alert('success')
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('error')
          },
      }); 
  });
```

Php

```
function ajax_form(){
      global $wpdb;

      $wpdb->update( 'my_plugin_table' ,
          array( 'settings_value' => $_POST[ 'field-one' ] ),
          array( 'settings_name'  => 'field-one'           ),
          array( '%s' , '%s' )
      );

      //echo something here to return a value...
      exit(); //prevent 0 in the return

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_form', 'ajax_form' ); //admin side
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_form', 'ajax_form' ); //for frontend
```